# Getting this error while building a react-native iOS app on xcode: `React/RCTBridgeModule.h` file not found

Tags: react-native

`React/RCTBridgeModule.h` file not found
after a while of searching, here is my solution:
1. Disable the parallel builds:

```
+++Xcode menu -> Product -> Scheme -> Edit Schemes...
+++Double click on your application
+++Build tab -> uncheck Parallelize Build
+++Click on the '+' sign, then add React

enter image description here:
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeEdK.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4w3pC.png
```